Do these pictures of human gestational sacs include embryos, and, if so, where?
This article in the Guardian, What a pregnancy actually looks like before 10 weeks – in pictures, includes a number of pictures of human gestational sacs.  The article seems to imply that each picture "includes the nascent embryo", but I'm puzzled because I think that the embryo should be visible in these pictures, yet it is not.  For example, the seventh picture in the article shows a gestational sac removed after eight weeks of pregnancy.  I believe this is a gestational age, measured from the last menstrual period, so according to this embryological info the embryo should be 8-11 mm long, and easily visible, given the scale of the pictures.  However, I don't see it at all.  Has the embryo been removed, or do these pictures include it, and if so, where?  You can also see these pictures here and here.  You can see some pictures of early embryos here.

Yes, it is visible, just mostly translucent.

The article also specifically says  hard to see: "This image shows the gestational sac of a nine-week pregnancy. This is everything that would be removed during an abortion and includes the nascent embryo, which is not easily discernible to the naked eye".

I can't point to a quantification, but I'd expect the embryo to be no more vascularized than any of the supporting tissue around it. I have much more experience (not much, just much more..) looking at other developing organisms at similar size and...yeah, they're pretty hard to see unless you have a stained histological specimen or something.
